# How to set the quality of YouTube video on UC Browser?

Tags: browser, video, youtube

I am using **UC Browser**. I can't find any option to set the quality of video in YouTube to *low* or *high*.

Comment: Just use the official app.... Also, why aren't you using chrome :/

Comment: @RahulBasu I personally don't use chrome either. There are a lot of better options that allow extensibility. I don't think it's possible to adjust this without using the app.

Comment: @RahulBasu I don't use Google Chrome because I think it opens the YouTube app to play videos, whereas UC Browser uses its own video player for playing. I think it UC Browser consumes less data then official YouTube app.

Comment: @user153722 - You cannot set quality of the video on YouTube in UC Browser. You just have to use the official app and set the quality to either 144p or 240p.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Low on UC Browser, but you can trick it using [Opera Max](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opera.max.global) (available on Google Play Store).